# VTK / Python / compile

Tags: python, compilation, cmake, vtk

I want to use VTK together with Python on a Windows system.

It seems that I cannot use the windows installer but "have to compile VTK from source code using CMake and a native build system". So far I have installed CMake.

But now I wonder how to proceed? It seems that I need MS Visual Studio to create the project files?!

But I don't have Visual Studio. So what can I do?

Comment: [Visual Studio Express edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express) is free.

Answer (score 8):

There is a VTK installer here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

It appears to work fine for me and it beats compiling it.

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't the case when you asked this question, but since version 6.1, vtk-python ships with a Windows (linux and osx) installer. See their [download page](http://www.vtk.org/VTK/resources/software.html#latestcand) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VTK with python just installing pythonxy framework, it is just a python with many many libraries included VTK, ITK, Qt and many other, also it is very well documented, and also have many examples, all in python. I recommend it to you, I have worked a lot with it, and is very amazing.
Just make a try. All you have to do is in the installer wizard select among the tools, VTK, and it will be installed with vtk.

Answer (score 0):

If 32bit is enough for you, I suggest looking into [Python(x,y)](http://pythonxynews.blogspot.in/). You get not only VTK but a whole lot of other useful scientific libraries.